# Partition Function for a singular potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I have an issue with calculating the Partition function for a certain class of potentials. Indeed, the fact that the value of an integral does not change if the integrand value is modified over a set of measure zero seems challenging.

In more detail, I would like to calculate the partition function for a potential $V(x) = \beta(x) + \alpha x^2$, where $\beta$ stands for
$$ \beta (x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
  \infty & ; & x< 0 \\ 0 & ; & x=0 \\ \delta & ; & x\neq 0 \end{array}\right. 
  $$
so, just an harmonic potential, coupled with an infintely high barrier for negative $x$ barrier and a "point" modification at the origin.
If I try to calculate the Partition function
$$Z = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-V(x)} \mathrm{d}x$$,

the value of $V$ at zero is totally irrelevant, as the origin in a set of meausure zero. That is already surprising.

I tried to regularise $\beta$, for example
$$ \beta (x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
 \infty & ; & x< 0 \\  \frac{\delta}{\epsilon} x & ; & 0 \leq x < \epsilon \\ \delta & ; & x> \epsilon  \end{array}\right. 
  $$

Then I can break the Partition function integral as $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-V(x)} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\epsilon} [\frac{\delta}{\epsilon} x + \alpha x^2 ] \mathrm{d}x  + \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} [\alpha x^2 + \delta] \mathrm{d}x$$

For sufficiently small $\epsilon$ I can approximate the first integral neglecting the quadratic term, and obtaining $$ \int_{0}^{\epsilon} [\frac{\delta}{\epsilon} x + \alpha x^2 ] \mathrm{d}x \approx \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}  (1 - e^{-\delta})$$. Not much I can do with the second term, apart from noting that for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, it continuously tends to 
$$ {1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}e^\delta $$ the same as the partition function I could have calculated at the beginning without regularisation. So in the Limit of $\epsilon$ going to zero, the presence of the potential Perturbation around the origin is forgotten. Is this correct? Is the formalism for calculating Partion functions to be refined when dealing with singular potentials?

Thanks

Comment: Is $\delta$ a constant? If so, $\beta$ in its original form is not a harmonic potential.

Comment: And isn't the integrand in the partition function $e^{-H}$, rather than $e^{-V}$?

Comment: $\delta $ is constant indeed. $\beta$ is not an harmonic potential, $V - \beta$ is (the term $\alpha x^2$). In my question, "so, just an harmonic potential, coupled with an infintely high barrier", should probably read, "so V is just an ..". As far as your second question is concerned, you are of course right. Let me then add that only the configurational part of the Partition function is sought, and the kinetic energy part has already been taken account of, upon decomposing $Z = Z_{kinetic} + Z_{config}$. The $Z$ in my question corresponds to the $Z_{config}=$.

Comment: How are you certain that such a decomposition can be performed? If we write $H=K+V$ the correct decomposition should be $Z=Z_{kinetic}Z_{config}$, and that's only if the two terms are completely independent. And even then, if either of those terms become unbounded then you may have screwed yourself over by not allowing some helpful cancellation from the kinetic term to occur.

Comment: I have indeed meant a multiplicative decomposition, it is hard not to be able to delete/edit my own mess. In any case, one could also assume that only the configurational part exist (massless particles?, for example). Are you suggesting that the answer to my issues depends critically on whether the kinetic term exists or not? Many thanks for the help

Comment: That is precisely what I am suggesting. In the case of massless particles, energy can no longer be decomposed into kinetic and potential parts, and you step into the world of relativistic statistical mechanics, which I promise is more complicated.

Comment: Interesting. Let me then revert to the classical case, considering one particle with mass $m$. Then $Z = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} exp-{V(x)+ m\dot{x}^2} \mathrm{d}\dot{x} \mathrm{d}x$. The multiplicative decomposition $Z=Z_{kinetic} Z_{config}$ holds. I do not immediately see how the kinetic terms could help. I am pondering the matter further. Many thanks.

Comment: Neither do I, just a thought I had.